# Search Field in Website

Tags: css, html

I want to add a search field in my website so that visitors can search anything which is on my website like many websites have. Can anyone guide me how can i add that.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?? here is your answer https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969?hl=en but you should describe what have you tried on your side ?

Comment: @Garry i dont have any idea

Comment: So you can try to use Google search that is a simple idea unless you want a custom search.https://www.google.ca/cse/

Comment: Do you want a Google search implementation or you want to search in your own website?

Comment: @Ankit i want to search in my own site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many possibilities to achieve internal search on your website. The easiest way which you can use is Google Search on you website. Google search code will not allows you to change any Google properties like logo and look and feel (You need Paid version to do that).

Another option is to create your own Database where you can have all keywords and metadata entry in table(s) and you can map respective table(s) with some key based on the content of the pages of your website.

I assume you are fine with Google Code, and below is the work around for that:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var domainroot="www.mywebsite.com"

function mySiteSearch(srcobj){
srcobj.q.value="site:"+domainroot+" "+srcobj.srctxt.value
}

</script>


<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="mySiteSearch(this)">

<p>Search your result: <input name="q" type="hidden" /> <input name="srctxt" type="text" style="width: 180px" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>

</form>
```

I hope this will work for you.